# Xamarin android, Windows 8.1 emulator error on Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am running VS 2015 Enterprise on Win 10 Enterprise. My box is not a physical machine, it is a VM on Azure. I do not get these errors on physical box VS. I suspect this is due to VM. Please guide how these can be resolved.

> 3>DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during
>   bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device
>   'A6BAF594-9315-40C3-AD16-F5B8A425A7AB'.': 3>SystemException - A method
>   was called on an uninitialized object

[image: error]

Comment: I think you can't use emulators on VM

Answer (score 0):

Now, It is not posible. Android Emulator and Windows Emulator  is itself a VM, you're not going to have any luck getting it to run in a VM. 
  Perhaps it will be available in the future. Running a VM inside another VM, is something [Microsoft is working on](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/nesting?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).